# Delayed functions after asynchronous call still being called before the asynchronous ones

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, core-data, alamofire

So I have 3 functions that needs to do the following :

1. `fetchNewMetaData()` Fetch data from webserver using Alamofire & sync the JSON response with the Core Data Entity using SyncDB.
2. `fetchCurrentMetaObjects()` Fetch objects from Core Data Entity and appends those objects to an array of `[NSManagedObject]`.
3. `applyLabels(label:UILabel, metaKey:String)` Apply a value of the array of `[NSManagedObject]` to the specified label according to the metaKey provided.

Here are the functions code :

```
var items = [NSManagedObject]()

func fetchNewMetaData() {
    let parameters: Parameters = ["email": email!, "password": password!]
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
    Alamofire.request("https://mywebsite.com/Sync.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in            
        if let jsonResult = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(jsonResult)
            let jsonData = json["data"]
            print("JSON DATA : \(jsonData)")
            let jsonString = jsonData.description
            let stringData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let serializedJSON = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: stringData!, options: []) as! [[String : Any]]

            Sync.changes(serializedJSON, inEntityNamed: "Usermeta", dataStack: self.dataStack) { error in
                self.fetchCurrentMetaObjects()
            }
        }
    }
}

func fetchCurrentMetaObjects() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Usermeta")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "remoteID", ascending: true)]
    self.items = (try! dataStack.mainContext.fetch(request)) as! [NSManagedObject]
}

func applyLabels(label:UILabel, metaKey:String) {
    for item in items as! [NSManagedObject] {
        if let savedMetaKey = item.value(forKey: metaKey) as? String {
            label.text = savedMetaKey
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call those functions using the following code, the label doesn't change :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fetchNewMetaData()
    self.fetchCurrentMetaObjects()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.applyLabels(label: self.label, metaKey: "firstName")
    }
}
```

I found a few threads talking about dispatch groups and queues on SO but all of them we're based on Swift 2 or Obj-C syntax and nothing applied to Swift 3. Would something know what would be the problem here ? I know for a fact that the data is saved to CoreData but it looks like `applyLabels()` is getting called before `fetchcNewMetaData()` and `fetchCurrentMetaObjects()` are.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The fetchNewMetaData method will return before you have received your alamofire response. If you set breakpoints in that method you will notice it hits the last } at the end of the method before it goes into the Alamofire response, then it will return and hit the Alamofire response a moment later.

I assume you want to call the methods in the following order?
fetchNewMetaData -> once you get response -> fetchCurrentMetaObjects -> when this is done -> apply labels

If that is the case, call fetchCurrentMetaObjects within the alamofire call, right after the Sync.change, this means that fetchCurrentMetaObjects won't be called until you get a response.

Then, call applyLabels right at the end of fetchCurrentMetaObjects within DispatchQueue.main.async.

In your viewDidLoad, all you should call is fetchNewMetaData, and then it should go in order. Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: That's the exact order I want them in ! I was able to make it work using your method ! Only problem I'm facing now is that by calling `applyLabels` inside `fetchCurrentMetaObjects` I'm forced to include the `label:UILabel & metaKey:String` parameters in both function, which in turns forces the app to do a complete Alamofire request + a DB Sync everytime I'm requesting a field. So on ViewControllers where I have 6-7 fields to request, I assume this would take a certain amount of time to accomplish the task. Do you have an idea of a solution to keep the `label` & `metaKey` out?